# Data change when saved in Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My code is this

```
db_con=Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testing')
db_con.query("insert into users(comment_id) values('39y5w57e43ujv54nlrni4adihhr37jofs9g2st9r46mrqc77wyvpk23qb8f1il')
```

but save in db

```
4xgyoq56j823pb63wu8pn62o82gte9nic583re9emuuagfhcokn08uq1hmk3ls
```

and table structure is `comment_id varchar(255)`
how can i solve this

Comment: Please, elaborate. What is the table schema? How do you verify the result? What is the DB Version? Why do you have "comment_id" column in the users table?

Comment: some reasons user can do comment on any site and i want to save it

Comment: Have you tried adding and retrieving data via MySQL's command line? I think it might be a problem with the column type you have used. Are you sure it is indeed varchar?

Comment: provide database schema if you are looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

you're doing something wrong, go through this list:

1. are you sure **new** record is inserted?
2. are you sure you're looking at correct table?
3. are you sure you're looking at correct database?

if it's a testing database try truncating the table(dropping all records from there) and showing before/after contents.

Comment: yes sure data is inserted and table is correct because and use all possible cases